# Why is sopln() giving error?

Tags: java

```
public class Gfg {

    // constructor
    Gfg()
    {
        System.out.println("Geeksforgeeks");
    }

    System.out.println("hi");


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Gfg b; 
        b = new Gfg();
    }

}
```

When I am writing `sopln()` in `main()` or in method in class then it is not giving any error but when I am writing it in class as above then it is giving error. Why so?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly.  See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `System.out.println("hi");` should be inside `{}`

Comment: Why? Because it is not allowed according to Java syntax. And btw. it is also unclear what this would mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because any expression statement in java should be between `{}` so you can use it inside a method like main method or inside a static block for example :

```
{
  System.out.println("hi");
}
```

Take a look [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/statement-2034294) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap up the statement in a method, like

```
public class Gfg {

    Gfg(){
        System.out.println("Geeksforgeeks");
        dummyMethod();
    }

    public void dummyMethod(){
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
..///rest of code
```